# MVC EF Oracle: How do I use a sequence to generate the next ID on insert?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Using MVC 5, EF 6, Oracle, and database first. I'm trying to auto-generate the ID of an object called Mission. Currently in the database there is a stored procedure which does this by using a sequence, MISSION_SEQ, on the insert command. I'm having trouble getting this stored procedure to work, so I thought I could try to handle it myself like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "<a bunch of fields, but I removed the MISSION_ID field")] MISSION mission)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string query = "select MISSION_SEQ.NEXTVAL from MISSION_SEQ";
        var query_result = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(query); //throws error "sequence not allowed here"
        decimal mission_id = query_result.First();
        mission.MISSION_ID = (decimal)mission_id;
        db.MISSION.Add(mission);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(mission);
}
```

This throws an error "Sequence not allowed here" I guess because you can only use NEXTVAL in an insert statement. I think I could just query the current MISSION_IDs and generate the next one by adding 1 to it, but how can I ensure that if multiple users are doing a create, they each get a unique number? Also if the Create fails, will that MISSION_ID be lost? I'm looking for any help to point me in the right direction here. Thanks.

Comment: select MISSION_SEQ.NEXTVAL from DUAL instead of MISSION_SEQ itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to use DUAL instead of the sequence name:

`string query = "select MISSION_SEQ.NEXTVAL from DUAL";`

Comment: OMG I'm dumb. I saw the DUAL from the statement that I took my code from, but I thought that was the name of a table in their database or something. I just looked up what DUAL is and it makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I just noticed it is incrementing by 2 instead of 1. The sequence says increment 1. The previous ID was 25. The Start With number is 26. When I did the create, I got back 27. Am I doing something wrong or is there something going somewhere else? There aren't any triggers running. No errors thrown either.

Comment: nevermind. I think the issue was I had a line "if query_result.Count() > 0" or something like that. I think that was re-running the query which incremented the id once more. Removed that line and all is well.