# “(ORA-02287) sequence number not allowed here” error when inserting a data into database through ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have a table in my database for model `Box`. I'm trying to insert new data with its ID there through an ASP.NET application. The ID itself is generated from a sequence named `box_seq`.

This is the context class:

```
using ApiProject.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ApiProject.Data
{
    public class GeneralContext: DbContext
    {
        public GeneralContext(DbContextOptions<GeneralContext> options): base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Box> BoxDatabase { get; set; } = default!;
        public long SetNewId()
        {
            var query = Database.SqlQueryRaw<long>("SELECT box_seq.nextval FROM dual");
            long id = query.Single();
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

The method `SetNewId()` is called here in the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ApiProject.Data;
using ApiProject.Models;
using ApiProject.Models.Requests;

namespace ApiProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BoxesController: ControllerBase
    {
        …
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Box>> create(BoxRequest request)
        {
            if (_context.BoxDatabase == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'GeneralContext.BoxDatabase' is null.");
            }
            var result = new Box
            {
                Id = _context.SetNewId(),
                XLength = request.XLength,
                YLength = request.YLength,
                ZLength = request.ZLength,
            };
            _context.BoxDatabase.Add(result);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { id = result.Id }, result);
        }
        …
    }
}
```

The ID fails to be added into the new data. It returns an error like this:

```
(ora-02287) sequence number not allowed here
```

There are solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155090/ora-02287-sequence-number-not-allowed-here) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183659/ora-02287-when-inserting-sequence-value-into-oracle-table) but they involve directly inserting the next value into the insert statement, and I don't know if it's possible in ASP.NET. There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085678/mvc-ef-oracle-how-do-i-use-a-sequence-to-generate-the-next-id-on-insert) where the case uses ASP.NET, but the problem comes just from wrong query and mine already follows the answer there.
Also, I've tried variations of `SetNewId()` body like these:

```
        public long SetNewId()
        {
            var query = Database.SqlQuery<long>($"SELECT box_seq.nextval FROM dual;");
            long id = query.Single();
            return id;
        }
```

```
        public long SetNewId()
        {
            var query = Database.SqlQuery<long>($"SELECT NEXT VALUE FROM box_seq;");
            long task = query.SingleAsync();
            long id = task.Result;
            return id;
        }
```

The former returned `(ora-02287) sequence number not allowed here` while the latter returned “missing right parenthesis”. Meanwhile, this:

```
        public long SetNewId()
        {
            var query = Database.SqlQuery<long>("SELECT box_seq.nextval FROM dual;");
            long id = query.Single();
            return id;
        }
```

Returns a warning `cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.FormattableString'`.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about ASP.NET.

However, as Oracle is involved, a few suggestions (if I may).

If your database version supports it, use an **identity** column and let Oracle generate values for you; in the background, it'll still be a sequence.

```
SQL> create table box
  2    (id      number generated always as identity,
  3     name    varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into box (name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from box;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Littlefoot

SQL>
```

---

If you can't (or don't want to) use it, back to your own sequence, this time as column's default value:

```
SQL> drop table box;

Table dropped.

SQL> create sequence box_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> create table box
  2    (id     number default box_seq.nextval,
  3     name   varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into box (name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from box;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Littlefoot

SQL>
```

---

Yet another option, the one we used for *ages*, is to have a sequence and a database trigger which will insert it into a table:

```
SQL> drop table box;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table box
  2    (id    number,
  3     name  varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_box
  2    before insert on box
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := box_seq.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into box (name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from box;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         2 Littlefoot             --> ID = 2 because I reused already 
                                      existing sequence from previous example
```

---

If solution to your problem has to involve ASP.NET (I guess so), you'll have to wait for someone else to assist.

Comment: Fyi my table's ID column is originally created as `ID NUMBER NOT NULL`. It uses sequence like the 2nd solution but can't take the next value by itself. Instead, there was a non-ASP.NET MVC application that made the queries to insert it. Anyway, thanks for the answer, I'll look it.

Comment: You're welcome. Though, I don't quite understand what "... the 2nd solution but **can't take the next value by itself**" means. Why not? It is all in the database, nothing (outside of it) should be used to make it work, that's *built-in* functionality.

Comment: Sorry for wording it vaguely, but basically the ID won't be ‘auto-generated’. You have to take the next value from the sequence, then make an insert query to put the next value into the ID column along with the new data. Otherwise, the ID of the new data would be null and rejected.